# Можно ли вывести все php скрипты обрабатывающие запрос в 1 цельную простыню(файл)?

Tags: php, laravel

К примеру у меня есть 2 скрипта php
В первом я подключаю второй при помощи include/require
Можно ли получить/вывести на экран весь объединённый код?

Нужно для изучения внутренностей сложных фреймворков, не охота прыгать из файла в файл когда их количество очень велико

Comment: Зачем и почему? Лучше изучите что и как работает

Comment: чтобы не бегать по множеству файлов, а видеть полную картину в одном

Comment: еще больше каши будет, IDE нормальный поставь, а не notepad++

Comment: PhpStorm стоит))

Answer (score 0):

Большинство современных фреймворков построены на ООП. Поэтому думать о ООП фреймворке как о простыне файлов - категорически не правильно. Больший вес имеют пространства имен, наследования и расширения.

---

Есть аналогичный метод - называется **трассировка скриптов** (**BackTrace**). Данный метод конечно не выводит всю простыню кода, но позволяет отследить весь стек вызовов функций и методов, который как раз и используют для изучения внутренностей сложных проектов.

```
debug_print_backtrace ( int $options, int $limit );
```

Где **options** это битовая маска (флаги) и **limit** ограничение трассировки. Подробнее - в документации https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.debug-print-backtrace.php

Comment: благодарю, понял что проще все же взять моник с 4к и прыгать по файлам, видя больше кода на екране